# View overlapping with Toolbar using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm having an issue of an overlapping ListView with a compat Toolbar using the ConstraintLayout
All i want to do is have a toolbar and then in the rest of the space have a listview. Pretty simple

This is my layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

  <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_toolbar2"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm not sure if the problem is that ListView's `layout_height` has precedence over everything else so to fit a ListView as high as the parent for sure there's either overlap or truncation at the bottom given that the toolbar took some space. 
What's the right way to make the ListView take the remaining vertical space after the toolbar?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this, should work:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_area"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this worked but the nested `ConstraintLayout` was unnecessary. The trick was the layout_width and height = "0dp" instead of `match_parent`. I didn't know 0 had a special meaning here

Comment: Great answer, I just think that the second ConstraintLayout is not necessary, app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" can be put directly on ListView with android:layout_height="0dp"

Comment: nothing is working for me. I tried putting 0dp Still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 26):

As per the official docs of [**ConstraintLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints) :

- You need to use `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` (0dp) instead of  MATCH_PARENT

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a
> ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using
> MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom
> constraints being set to "parent".

Just change Listview widht & height = **"0dp"**

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_toolbar2"/>
```

Comment: Upvote for that explanation..I've been struggling with constraint layout for a while now but couldn't find time to read the docs..

Comment: setting view height to 0dp means that the view will cover the entire space left out by other views right? An upvote for that solution!

Answer (score 2):

Used below method for add `Toolbar`

```
- <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout> or ConstraintLayout
    -<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
       - <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
       - </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   - </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  -<LinearLayout
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
     -<ListView>
     -</Listview>
  -</LinearLayout>
-</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout> or ConstraintLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. Should be work.
use this code inside constraint layout.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your ListView to set scrolling and spacing behaviour. It works with CoordinatorLayout or RelativeLayout, probably it will work with ConstraintLayout too.

Comment: i had tried this. It doesn't work. everything looks exactly the same

Answer (score -1):

Basically Framelayout trying to overlap other views thats why its happening, try put framelayout in other viewgroup

Cheers