# ConstraintLayout with RecyclerView Top and Buttom views some part are invisible.

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overlap, android-constraintlayout, invisible

From 2 months I'm playing with ConstrainLayout but every time I face a few problems and after spending a lot of time I find the solution but now I'm in a deathlock. My view upper part is hidden by the status bar and lower part also hidden by navigation bar.

**How my view display in device** 
[image: overlap view]

**Here you can see my AppBar is below status bar and also the RecyclerView last item is not showing complete. It's some view is unvisible.**

I'm not sure where is the problem, previously I solve such kinds of problems by adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` but now it's not working. And also it's behave different when I try applying googles result.

**This is my view xml code**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/shop_recycler_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/shop_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar"
    tools:listitem="@layout/shop_list_recycler_view_row" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please use the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49584773/1020704

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `CoordinatorLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` for the future features adding like hiding `Toolbar` or etc. However, using `CoordinatorLayout` seems to be the best choice here:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shop_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/shop_list_recycler_view_row" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will use CoordinatorLayout in future, and now I solved this problem by adding RecyclerView height to 0dp.

Comment: Why 0? Are you using `LinearLayout` as the root layout forthe `RecyclerView`? You don't need to make it 0. Just use `match_parent`. please consider accepting the answer if it helped.